# How to set default value of a vector of int pairs to be empty?

Tags: c++, c++98

I want to gave a default value (of empty) for a vector of int pairs in a constructor (C++ 98). I've tried things along the following and it (obviously) doesn't work. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
SomeClassName(
const int replace = 1, 
const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > node = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>() >()
);
```

Comment: A vector defaults to having no elements upon creation, unless you give constructor arguments. A pair does not support “empty”. I’m not sure which of these you meant; please try to be clearer in your questions. Additionally, `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>() >` denotes a type, not construction, and a different type than `std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >`.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is how do I assign a 'empty' vector as the default to my constructor?

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<std::pair<int, int>() >()` is a value-initialized (empty for `std::vector`) instance of a vector of functions taking nothing and returning `std::pair<int, int>`. Simply remove the inner `()` to get a vector of pairs:

```
const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > node = std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >()
```

You might also want to consider a typedef because there's a lot of noise:

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > Node;
...
const Node node = Node()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to write a constructor that accepts a `vector` as input, and you want to make that argument optional, then either:

1. define two constructors, one that takes a `vector` and one that doesn't:

   ```
   SomeClassName(
       const int replace = 1
   );

   SomeClassName(
       const int replace,
       const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > &node
   );
   ```
2. define a single constructor that takes the `vector` argument with a default-constructed `vector` as a default value (this is what you are already trying to do, but your syntax is wrong):

   ```
   SomeClassName(
       const int replace = 1,
       const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > &node = std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >()
   );
   ```